# How to get order total in my payment method

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom payment method to my wordpress project. In my plugin within the process_payment function i used this code for getting cart total amount.

```
$cart_tot=$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
```

This out put the total as follows at the mysql.

```
<span class="amount">&pound;250</span>
```

But i want to get the integer value only. Is this possible? If so how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
  global $woocommerce;
```

and then you can get the content with

```
  $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total
```